# rxjs merging http data with websocket update

Tags: rxjs

I have a couple of arrays of data obtained from an api call

```
    protected ngUnsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

    const users$ = this.userApi
        .find<User>()
        .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
        .share();

    this.active$ = users$.map(users =>
        users.filter(user => user.status === 'active')
    );

    this.archived$ = users$.map(users =>
        users.filter(user => user.status === 'inactive')
    );
```

then another user in a different session updates a user record, changing it from active to inactive.

The server notifies my session of this updated user using websockets.

This is now where I am stuck ... how can I modify the `$active` and `$archive` observables to reflect this change of data ?

Comment: Does `this.userApi.find<User>()` call an http endpoint, maybe via Angular http client?

Answer (score 0):

so I got this to work by using the following:

```
const data = await this.userApi
        .find<User>()
        .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
        .share()
        .toPromise();

    const data$ = new BehaviorSubject<User[]>(data);

    this.active$ = data$.map(users => {
        return users.filter(user => user.status === 'active');
    });

    this.archived$ = data$.map(users => {
        return users.filter(user => user.status !== 'active');
    });
```

now whenever I get an update / delete / create from the websocket, I manipulate the data array accordingly and do a

```
data$.next(data)
```

to get updated data